# Wireshark: display filters vs nested dissectors

Tags: lua, wireshark, amqp, wireshark-dissector

I have an application that sends JSON objects over AMQP, and I want to inspect the network traffic with Wireshark.  The AMQP dissector gives the payload as a series of bytes in the field `amqp.payload`, but I'd like to extract and filter on specific fields in the JSON object, so I'm trying to write a plugin in Lua for that.

Wireshark already has a dissector for JSON, so I was hoping to piggy-back on that, and not have to deal with JSON parsing myself.

Here is my code:

```
local amqp_json_p = Proto("amqp_json", "AMQP JSON payload")
local amqp_json_result = ProtoField.string("amqp_json.result", "Result")
amqp_json_p.fields = { amqp_json_result }
register_postdissector(amqp_json_p)

local amqp_payload_f = Field.new("amqp.payload")
local json_dissector = Dissector.get("json")

local json_member_f = Field.new("json.member")
local json_string_f = Field.new("json.value.string")

function amqp_json_p.dissector(tvb, pinfo, tree)
   local amqp_payload = amqp_payload_f()
   if amqp_payload then
      local payload_tvbrange = amqp_payload.range
      if payload_tvbrange:range(0,1):string() == "{" then
         json_dissector(payload_tvbrange:tvb(), pinfo, tree)
         -- So far so good.  Let's look at what the JSON dissector came up with.
         local members = { json_member_f() }
         local strings = { json_string_f() }
         local subtree = tree:add(amqp_json_p)
         for k, member in pairs(members) do
            if member.display == 'result' then
               for _, s in ipairs(strings) do
                  -- Find the string value inside this member
                  if not (s < member) and (s <= member) then
                     subtree:add(amqp_json_result, s.range)
                     break
                  end
               end
            end
         end
      end
   end
end
```

(To start with, I'm just looking at the `result` field, and the payload I'm testing with is `{"result":"ok"}`.)

It gets me halfway there.  The following shows up in the packet dissection, whereas without my plugin I only get the AMQP section:

```
Advanced Message Queueing Protocol
    Type: Content body (3)
    Channel: 1
    Length: 15
    Payload: 7b22726573756c74223a226f6b227d
JavaScript Object Notation
    Object
        Member Key: result
            String value: ok
            Key: result
AMQP JSON payload
    Result: "ok"
```

Now I want to be able to use these new fields as display filters, and also to add them as columns in Wireshark.  The following work for both:

- `json` (shows up as `Yes` when added as a column)
- `json.value.string` (I can also filter with `json.value.string == "ok"`)
- `amqp_json`

But `amqp_json.result` doesn't work: if I use it as a display filter, Wireshark doesn't show any packets, and if I use it as a column, the column is empty.

Why does it behave differently for `json.value.string` and `amqp_json.result`?  And how can I achieve what I want?  (It seems like I do need a custom dissector, as with `json.value.string` I can only filter on *any* member having a certain value, not necessarily `result`.)

---

I found [a thread on the wireshark-dev mailing list](http://wireshark-dev.wireshark.narkive.com/qMnA5KPY/lua-post-dissector-not-getting-field-values) ("Lua post-dissector not getting field values", 2009-09-17, 2009-09-22, 2009-09-23), that points to the `interesting_hfids` hash table, but it seems like the code has changed a lot since then.

If you'd like to try this, here is my PCAP file, base64-encoded, containing a single packet:

```
1MOyoQIABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAjBi1WfYOCgBjAAAAYwAAAB4AAABgBMEqADcGQA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB/tcWKO232y46mkSqgBgxtgA/AAAB
AQgKRjDNvkYwzb4DAAEAAAAPeyJyZXN1bHQiOiJvayJ9zg==
```

Decode with `base64 -d` (on Linux) or `base64 -D` (on OSX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I shouldn't have tried to compare the `display` property of the `json.member` field.  Sometimes it gets set by the JSON dissector, and sometimes it just stays as `Member`.

The proper solution would involve checking the value of the `json.key` field, but since the key I'm looking for presumably would never get escaped, I can get away with looking for the string literal in the `range` property of the member field.

So instead of:

```
            if member.display == 'result' then
```

I have:

```
            if member.range:range(1, 6):string() == 'result' then
```

and now both filtering and columns work.