# How to implement own dissector to dissect payload of AMQP?

Tags: tcp, lua, wireshark, amqp, wireshark-dissector

right now I am struggling with implementing a functionality to dissect my own protocol within the payload of AMQP.

There is no problem dissecting it if it's only send via TCP.. But if AMQP is on top of it, there seems to be some problems.

Right now I have only those links which aren't very much helpful :(

[Wireshark: display filters vs nested dissectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149825/wireshark-display-filters-vs-nested-dissectors)

In the moment my code is very much like in the example link, but I don't know how to reference my own dissector.

I can provide code - but it looks very much as the example but without the JSON part.

I appreciate every help! Thank you!

Comment: it might help if you would describe the observed problems.

Comment: the problem is that I have no clue how to use my dissector to dissect the payload within AMQP